# Get data from MS ACCESS Database that is saved in a shared folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I am creating an Employee Evaluation form using HTML/CSS. The Management team was asking if there's a way to add dynamic graphs or reports within the form. I understand it is possible but here's my scenario:

- I am saving the HTML file in a Sharepoint Page
- The raw data where for the graph can only be either in Excel or Access that is saved in a shared folder within the company
- I don't have access to the servers.

Having said that, is it possible to pull data from an access database saved in a shared folder? If Javascript or PHP is needed to accomplish this, I am willing to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript is client-side, PHP is server-side. which one you want? You'd probably need server-side. But you're working with MS products, so you'd better stick with ASP.NET.

Comment: is there a workaround where I will only use pure client side? remember I'm saving the raw data in a shared folder.

Comment: JavaScript has no permission to reach your shared drive.